# Retrieve information from JPA Metamodel

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, metamodel

Jpa 2 metamodel has one known use: type safe criteria query. My question is different: I suppose metamodel can be source of information like length, human friendly description, left-right alligment etc, for example for building pretty GUI table (desktop or web, no matter). 
I imagine such quasi code:

```
SomeTable st = buildTable(Person_.class, Person_.surName, Person_.Height)
```

Tell me, I'm thinking in wrong way? My google research give no result. Or give some info to start reading

EDIT: auto correction, human friendly Column name is not in strict JPA area, but in other annotation family (validation is near to JPA / extension).

Comment: metamodel does not provide schema information like table name, column name, etc. It is basic class/field type info only.

Comment: You can get this details with SQL, getting this level of underlying details seems difficult with JPA.

Comment: My goal is one (btw like in Criteria API idea): say short: to have safe non-string realisation info about fields (lets say string are unsafe). Now (one month later) I have partial but positive effects. My API has first-contanct with metamodel, then switch from metamodel (quite poor but non-string based) info  to bean reflection (all JPA annotations etc)