# Access to class' Fields without using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way to access a specific `Field` on a class without using reflection?

Consider this class:

```
class MyType {
    public int theNumber;
}
```

Where I would like to get access to `theNumber`'s  `java.lang.reflect.Field`.

This works for sure:

```
Field f = MyType.class.getDeclaredField("theNumber");
```

However, I would like compile check on the field name, so ideally something like this instead (but of course my example doesn't compile):

```
Field f = MyType.class::theNumber;
```

Is this possible or am I way of wrt the compiler abilities?

Comment: I try to feel Your background, motivation(?) to question. I try to resolve similar (or reverse) idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284675/retrieve-information-from-jpa-metamodel Sorry for "hidden advertising" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the java compiler with annotation processors. This processors are a way to scan your source code during compile. They were introduced with Annotations but they are able to scan the whole source code not only annotations.

With the scanned Source-Code you can generate accessor classes to any class you compile. This way you can eliminate reflection.

If you only want to get errors while you write code in your IDE you can make use of javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment.getMessager().printMessage() (see also javax.tools.DiagnosticListener) to generate Errors the IDE can show.

So the basic Idea is:

1. write an annotation processor which scans the source code you want to reflect
2. extract the field you want to have access to via javax.lang.model.element.ElementVisitor

In case you want to generate type save access to Field:

3.1. generate source that will access this source code

In case you want to ensure, that a reflective call to a field is valid:

3.2. raise an Error via ProcessingEnvironment.getMessager().printMessage()

Of course you have to write the code for checking reflective calls or generating the accessors.

And the information you want to get must be extractable from the sourcecode since all the magic happens during the compile and not at runtime

Comment: Wow, I learnt something new there, didn't know about annotation processors. I will definitely check that out!

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. No, there's no way to do that without using `java.lang.reflect`, but given the built-in `class` pseudo-property on classes, I can see why you'd ask.

Comment: Thought so. Right now I'm using an enum with values that equal field names in the class. Was hoping to get rid of that since every field name is repeated in the enum.

Answer (score 0):

JPA2 Metamodel (used in typesafe queries "by criteria") has similar concept.

```
MyType_.theNumber
```

Is implemented by extra "pre-processors". You can investigate in this area.

Answer (score -1):

No, It's not... but you could achieve it with an interface and a closure

```
public interface Getter<T, V> {
    V get(T object);
}

public static Getter<MyType, Integer> theNumberGetter = (MyType myType) -> { myType.theNumber };
```

Comment: That doesn't access the `Field`, it accesses the *value* of the field on a given instance.

Comment: Understood... but I'm guessing he only wants the `Field` so that he can access values later

Comment: Well, to do that, simply `myTypeInstance.theNumber` seems the more direct way, if you know the name of the field at compile-time.

Comment: He DOES know the field at compile time... but sometimes to write generic code you need constructs like this. Let's see what @Geir says

Comment: As pointed out above I do know the field at compile time. I am trying to write a generic SQL builder which is type safe when referencing table column names, and also doesn't require duplication of column names (e.g defining them in an enum). Example `db.select(MyType::thenumber).from(...)`. @truthslie and @jacek-cz seem to have provided som valuable clues which I will follow up!